# Subsequence : Error in instructor's correction?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

http://faculty.usiouxfalls.edu/sjc/fall_06/mat320_soln/hmk10.pdf

12. Show that if ($x_n$) is unbounded, then there exists a subsequence ($x_{n_k}$) such that lim $1/x_{n_k} = 0$.

*Proof. By the Monotone Subsequence Theorem, there exists a subsequence
that is either increasing or decreasing. Let’s look at the increasing case.
This means that $x_{n_1} < x_{n_2} < . . . . $ Since the original sequence was
unbounded, we know that our subsequence has the same trait...*

I'm not good at drawing but I drew an unbounded sequence in which there exists a bounded monotone subsequence of peaks (the blue dots). If I read the author correctly, isn't he implying that any increasing monotone subsequence issued from an unbounded sequence will also be unbounded?

[image]

Comment: You are absolutely correct. The proof as stated is erroneous, for the reason you give.

Comment: @TonyK I disagree.  See my answer.

Comment: I agree with you and TonyK. I don't think the (normal) monotone subsequence theorem can be used for much here, though I don't know your version of it. Either your version has the special stronger case for unbounded sequences, which the author quoted wrong. Or you would need to prove an ad hoc version of it for the exercise. In any case, what we need is a monotone and diverging subsequence (which is easy enough to construct).

Answer (score -1):

Addendum added to respond to the comment/question of
pyFcGSxXs1lzE.

---

No, you have misinterpreted the author's assertion.  The author is not saying that the assertion will be true for any subsequence.  Instead, the author is saying that there exists at least one subsequence such that the assertion is true.

If I am interpreting your graphed attempt at a counter-example correctly, a subsequence from your example can be constructed that goes to $-\infty$.  This implies that the assertion is true, with respect to your attempted counter-example.

---

**Note** 
It just occurred to me that when the author stated (for example)

> By the Monoton Subsequence Theorem, there exists a subsequence
> that is either increasing or decreasing

he actually intended:

> By the Monoton Subsequence Theorem, there exists $\color{red}{\text{an unbounded}}$ subsequence
> that is either increasing or decreasing

Further, I surmise that what the author is trying to say is that if the sequence is **unbounded above**, then there exists a subsequence that is strictly increasing, that is unbounded above.

So, a case could be made that the author did not clearly express his intent.

---

**Addendum**
Responding to the comment/question of
pyFcGSxXs1lzE.

> But does restricting the proof to sequences that are unbounded above sufficient to prove the general case? The problem states only that $x_n$ must be unbounded.

Either the sequence is unbounded above, or the sequence is unbounded below.  Assume, without loss of generality that the sequence is unbounded above.

Let $N$ be any positive integer.  Since the sequence is unbounded above, there must exist an element from the original sequence $~x_1, x_2, \cdots,~$ (denote this element as $a_N$) such that $a_N > N.$

Now, consider the positive integer $(N+1)$.  Since the sequence is unbounded above, there must exist an element from the original sequence $~x_1, x_2, \cdots,~$ (denote this element as $a_{N+1}$) such that

- $\displaystyle a_{N+1} > \max\left(N+1,a_N\right)$
- **and** the element $a_{N+1}$ occurs in the original sequence $x_1, x_2, \cdots$ **after** the element $a_N$.

This (iterative) process can be continued indefinitely.  So, you have **some** **constructed infinite subsequence** that is strictly increasing and goes to $+\infty.$

This establishes the author's claim that the **reciprocal** **subsequence**

$$\frac{1}{a_N}, \frac{1}{a_{N+1}}, \cdots$$ is a strictly positive, strictly decreasing subsequence that goes to $(0)$.

I surmise that although the author was **overly terse**, that this is what the author intended.

Comment: But does restricting the proof to sequences that are unbounded above sufficient to prove the general case? The problem states only that ($x_n$) must be unbounded.

Comment: @pyFcGSxXs1lzE See the Addendum that I have just added to my answer.

Comment: Your very first paragraph is wrong. The author _is_ implying that the assertion will be true for any increasing subsequence: "we know that our subsequence has the same trait". This is simply not true in general, as the OP clearly shows. I don't see how you can misunderstand this. Of course the proof can be corrected; the assertion is after all true. But the authors proof is just wrong.

Comment: @TonyK "By the Monoton Subsequence Theorem, there exists a subsequence that is either increasing or decreasing. Let’s look at the increasing case.  This means that $x_{n_1} < x_{n_2}  < \cdots$. Since the original sequences was
unbounded, we know that our subsequence has the same trait." : This is what I meant by the phrase **overly terse**.  The author is clearly intending that (when the original sequence is unbounded above), that there must exist some strictly increasing subsequence that is unbounded.  ...see next comment

Comment: @TonyK Technically, your criticism of the exact words used by the author is valid.  However, this is clearly not what the author intended.  The author did not intend to assert that if you have an unbounded (above) sequence, that any constructed strictly increasing subsequence must also be unbounded.  Instead, what the author clearly intended, but was overly terse about, is that there must exist **some** strictly increasing unbounded subsequence.

Comment: I can't read the author's mind, and neither -- with respect -- can you. What the author _wrote_ was false. End of story.